# How to find the actual valid version in maven?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, plugins

When I use maven, there may be multiple versions from comes from BOMs in dependencyManagement (import) and so on. How can I quickly confirm in which module the actual effective version is defined?
[image]

The actual effective version is 3.19.6, but the version defined in the actual avatica-core is 3.6.1
[image]

[image]

Is there any mvn command or tool to find out how version 3.19.6 takes effect?

I used

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree -Dverbose=true > maven2.json
```

command

Comment: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.10 is an old version based on Maven2 resolution, which might be slightly different to Maven3. Use at least 3.x (currently 3.5.0) to get an accurate version resolution. Running `mvn -X validate` should show you the actual tree as resolved by Maven, some plugins help to make this more visuable.

Comment: Thanks Robert.I just started using the maven 3.x version, the Dverbose parameter of maven 3.x does not take effect, and I cannot see the details of the overwritten version

Answer (score 0):

Use IntelliJ IDEA [Dependency Analyzer](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-dependencies.html#dependency_analyzer):

> Maven dependency analyzer lets you quickly see and analyze resolved dependencies, the unresolved ones, dependencies with conflicts, and transitive dependencies in your project and subprojects.

[image]